# python string conversion

Tags: python, fabric

Trying to add user with python fabric script.

```
uid = prompt("Enter username:")
eid = prompt("Enter user's email address:")
password = generate_passwd()
run('adduser -g vpn -c %s %s') % (eid, uid)
run("echo -e '%s\n' | passwd %s") % (password, uid)
print (password)
```

Error:

```
File "/tmp/hardway/fabfile.py", line 56, in addvpnuser
    run('adduser -g vpn -c %s %s') % (eid, uid)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're placing the string interpolation in the wrong place; it has to be directly after the string and not outside the parens.  (This is not specific to fabric, by the way.)

So

```
run('adduser -g vpn -c %s %s' % (eid, uid))
```

instead of

```
run('adduser -g vpn -c %s %s') % (eid, uid)
```

and

```
run("echo -e '%s\n' | passwd %s" % (password, uid))
```

instead of

```
run("echo -e '%s\n' | passwd %s") % (password, uid)
```

Comment: The same for the other one too (the "echo" line).